# to search for consecutive list elements prefixed by number and dot in plain text

Tags: regex, parsing, text-parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

The text looks like this:

```
"Beginning. 1. The container is 1.5 meters long 2. It can hold up to 2lt of fluid. 3. It 4 holes."
```

There may not be a dot at the end of each list element.

How can I split this text into a list as shown below?

```
"Beginning."
"The container is 1.5 meters long"
"It can hold up to 2lt of fluid."
"It has 4 holes."
```

In other words I need to match (\d+)\. such that all (\d+) are consecutive integers so that I can split and trim the text between them. Is it possible with regex? How far do I have to venture into the realm of computer science?

Comment: What if the container was 2.5 meters long?

Comment: +1 to Howard, that would be very unfortunate according to the way I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\d+\.(?!\d)
```

as the splitting regex, i. e. in PHP

```
$result = preg_split('/\d+\.(?!\d)/', $subject);
```

The negative lookahead `(?!\d)` ensures that no digit follows after the dot has been matched.

Or make the spaces mandatory - if that's an option:

```
$result = preg_split('/\s+\d+\.\s+/', $subject);
```

Comment: Good point, not matching floating point numbers, but ordered list prefixes only. This is the most complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is working c# code:

```
string s = "Beginning. 1. The container is 1.5 meters long 2. It can hold up to 2lt of fluid. 3. It has 4 holes.";
string[] res = Regex.Split(s, @"\s*\d+\.\s+");

foreach (var r in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I split on `\s*\d+\.\s+` that means optional white space, followed by at least one digit ,followed by a dot, then at least one whitespace.